# How to sort SortedDictionary using Key and Value together?

Tags: c#, collections

I have a `SortedDictionary` where the key is a reference to class Store. A value is `List<Item>`.

I want to sort the Stores in the dictionary.
`IComparer` can only be applied to the value of `Key`.

But for correct sorting need the data from the Value (`List<Item>`). Price for example.

How can I do this?
Use SortedDictionary optional , I will approach any decisions.
It is important that I could quickly get the value for a key, similarly `TryGetValue`.

```
class Item
{
  int price;
  string name;
}

class Store
{
  string owner;
  string street;
  string city;
}

SortedDictionary<Store, List<Item>>
```

Comment: maybe `SortedDictionary<Store, SortedSet<Item>>` ?

Comment: No, I need to sort the list/dictionary of Stores. Using data on the price of the goods.

Comment: You can make `List<Item>` part of `Store` class as a field and then you'd be able to sort list of stores the way you want.

Comment: @Yuriy
I thought about it.
But I can't do it logically.
List<Item> is a temporary list of received after text search

Comment: @Mixer I don't see a problem there.

Answer (score 0):

Well you can sort the list of stores using LINQ extension methods like `OrderBy` or `OrderByDescending`:

```
Dictionary<Store, List<Item>> stores;
...
var result = stores.OrderBy(pair => pair.Value.Min(item => item.price));
```